# Android and location of touch event

Tags: android, view, touch-event

In Android, we can set `OnClickListeners` for views.

But how do we intercept the location of the touch event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is method in `Activity`

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    int action = event.getAction();
    int x = event.getX()  
    int y = event.getY();
    return yourBoolean;
}
```

**Edit**: Or you can define `OnTouchListener` for any `View` and can use its method

```
public abstract boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event);
```

**Edit2**: the `x` and `y` values depends upon the method call. If you use `onTouchEvent()` of `Activity` then it indicates that no `View` consumes the touch event [see documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) and if you handle it on any `View` then the x and y will be according to the `View`'s area.

Comment: Thanks. Are the x- and y-coordinates relative to the view? Or relative to the screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `onTouchListener` for the same view. The `MotionEvent` will have the x and y.